# Stability theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, stability, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I'm studying [stability theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory) recently and met a lot of phrases like linear stability and nonlinear instability. After searching on Google, I became more confused. Thus I wonder if there is any approperiate or famous books discussing these issues of dynamical systems.

Comment: This is unfortunately incompatible with the [current policy on resource requests](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/reevaluating-the-book-policy).

Comment: I close this question (v2) as _off-topic_ because book recommendation questions fit poorly to the Q&A format of Phys.SE. In general Phys.SE only allows a limited number of book recommendation questions. For more information, see various meta posts, e.g. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4697/2451).

Answer (score 2):

A standard/famous book on dynamical systems, which is very good about nonlinear stability is "Nonlinear Dynamics And Chaos" by S. H. Strogatz.